# How to get the list of attributes on frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm using Magento 2, when I try add product in Backend, in the Configurations tab, I have created Configuration and I saw there three attributes.

[image]

How can I get them in a module on frontend?

I see they are stored in eav_attribute table but I dont know which SQL can be do it, because it has no conditional column
[image]

Thank so much!

Answer (score -2):

Use can use below code to get attribute in your module frontend.

```
$attribute = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$colorAttributeId= $attribute->getAttributeId();

foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true) as $option) {
    $colors[$option['value']] = strtolower($option['label']);
}

print_r($colors);
```